# Saving data from ViewPagerIndicator

Tags: java, android

I have been searching all over but I can't find any answer to this. I have ViewPagerIndicator working in my app but I simply cannot find any tutorial that shows how to use more than 3 pages. I want to use 6 pages. I can get 6 pages to display correctly but when I enter data on page 0 it disappears after I swipe over to page 3 (being recycled?). I've read over the ViewPagerIndicator.java but to be honest most of it is a little over my head at this time. What do I need to do to save the data on page 0 when swiping over to page 3. Can someone point me to an example. Also, what do I use to restore the data when swiping back to page 0?

Disclaimer: I am very new to both Java and Android development; this is my first app.

Thanks in advance for any guidance anyone can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5).  This will allow you to have 1 on-screen page and 5 off-screen pages, all in memory.  The default is 1, which is why you're seeing page 0 removed when you get to page 3.

Alternatively, you could implement instantiateItem to create/load each page and destroyItem to save each page inside of your PagerAdapter as documented in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html

Comment: The setOffscreenPageLimit worked. Thanks. I will read up on the create/load solution for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

1. To show >3 pages, say 6 pages you have to just add 6 pages on the ViewPager and the ViewPagerIndicator will automatically update itself to show 6 circles (indicators)
2. To save the data, I would suggest looking at setting a onPageChangeListener like the one mentioned here https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/sample/src/com/viewpagerindicator/sample/SampleCirclesWithListener.java

You can define whatever you want to do when the page is scrolled or whatever...

```
    mIndicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            Toast.makeText(SampleCirclesWithListener.this, "Changed to page " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            //save the data here
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: This looks like it will become more useful when I get past the navigation stage and start saving the data entered. I'm still so new to Android and Java that I'm struggling with getting a fluid navigation and look/feel.